# Recover data in recovery mode loop option in Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, redmi

My Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro is stuck in the recovery loop. I set my smallest width to 1020 in developer options, and after that, it went in the recovery loop and kept on rebooting again and again. If I select "reboot to system," then it gets back to recovery mode again and I am unable to connect to Mi assistant as there is no official Mi assistant find on the web.

I contacted a few mobile repair shops and they said that they had to flash the memory and wipe all data. However, I don't save my images on the cloud nor do I save them to Google Drive or any other file host, I only save them on the local drive on mobile which is why I need to fix it on normal mode or just copy and paste it to my PC.

Is there any way to get my data back or do I have to flash it with new software?

Comment: there is a chance to flash custom recovery and decrypt data from EDL mode with locked bootloader. but nobody will guide you